# Get CSS values in wicket

Tags: java, css, wicket

in my project i've faced a problem getting values of css attributes in wicket class, suppose we have  some Panel

```
public final class ExamplePanel extends Panel {

  public ExamplePanel(String id) {
      super(id);
      add(new Label("someText", "hello"));
  }}
```

and html file for this file is

```
<html xmlns:wicket>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>ExamplePanel</title>
    <wicket:head>
        <link href="panel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    </wicket:head>
</head>
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
        <div id="container" wicket:id="hello">
        </div>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
```

and the following css

```
#parentContainer{
 width:500px;
 height: 500px;
 background:RGB(57,51,51);
 position:relative;
}
```

i need to get values of css code, for example

```
public final class ExamplePanel extends Panel {

  public ExamplePanel(String id) {
      super(id);
      Label label = new Label("someText", "hello");
      add(label);
      // draft code
      //String height = label.getCssValue("height");
      // String position = label.getcssvalue("position");
  }}
```

Or any oher solution to get css values from this div?

Comment: It's pretty simple with jQuery. You would just use `$(element).css('height');` or `$(element).css('left')` and whatnot. If you're not using jQuery, there are strictly JS ways to get the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CSS is applied on the client side, your only chance would be to get the values by JavaScript (with the JQuery methods mentioned by Torr3nt being the easiest way that I know of) and post these values back to your App using Ajax.

There is a description on how to call wicket from JavaScript [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/calling-wicket-from-javascript.html).

Comment: yea, i've tried that, but i't doesn't work for me, after request, page tells that session page requested has expired

Comment: @ilya.stmn Without seeing any code I can't tell what went wrong there. So for further assistance, you'd need to post the code that didn't work.

Comment: i'm sorry just needed to apply some more attentiveness, thank's a lot, that's worked for me.

Comment: @ilya.stmn if it's the correct and/or working answer, it would be nice to accept it.